# Does joomla virtuemart support reordering?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Does joomla virtuemart support reordering of products.If a customer shops a set of products and will he/she able to order it repeatedly after a custom time period(for eg: 2 weeks).So that once he/she gives an order for the first time ,will he/she would be getting products every 2 weeks.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I know of doing this would be to edit the VM 'Save to cart' function. The VM forums explain how to save the cart in database and call each time the user logs in. This is a core hack so ensure you backup before trying.

Source: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=14790.0